# Encoding a JSON file

Tags: python, json, encoding

I get this string from the web

`'Probabilità'`

and I save it in a variable called `temp`. Than I stored it in a dictionary

```
dict["key"]=temp
```

Then I need to write all the dictionary in a JSON file and I use this function

```
json_data = json.dumps(dict)
```

But when I look at the JSON file written by my code I see this

```
'Probabilit\u00e0'
```

How can I solve this encoding problem?

Comment: Why is it a problem? Its up to the thing doing the decoding to deal with that

Comment: string.decode('utf8')???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `ensure_ascii` argument in the `json.dumps` call:

```
mydict = {}
temp = "Probabilità"
mydict["key"] = temp
json_data = json.dumps(mydict, encoding="utf-8", ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: I get this error...
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 351, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ensure_ascii'

Comment: Strange. According to the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps), it should work just fine.